# Absorance, and Transmittance Conversion in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to rewrite a CSV called TEST1.csv which is two columns, and I am trying to use this code except I don't understand how exactly to do it?

```
import fileinput

input_file = str(input("Input file for absorbance/transmittance to be inserted? ")) 

f1 = open(input_file, "r")

with open(str(input("What file name is it? ")), 'w') as f2:
for row in f1:
    f2.write( #Data from second row 2 gets 10**(-(A-2))  + "\n")

f1.close()
```

A is the values in that column, that is what they are called so all the numbers in the second column (A's) have to get that operation done on them, and rewritten with the new value. 10**(-(A-2))=T
The old CSV

```
X    A
X    A
X    A
```

The New One

```
X    T
X    T
X    T
```

Text file to be used:

```
 0,2.58612
 0.00616025,2.20018
 0.0123205,1.56186
 0.0184807,0.371172
 0.024641,0.327379
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? What's "A" in "gets 10**(-(A-2))"?

Comment: 3.7.0 is the Python Version I am using

Comment: @martineau A is the values in that column, that is what they are called so all the numbers in the second column (A's) have to get that operation done on them, and rewritten with the new value.

Comment: You want to import a csv , do some operation to its second row and then write it to a new file?

Comment: "A" is what the Excel spreadsheet application calls the first column — but not a general CSV term.

Comment: no its what I call it, A is just in general the second column.

Comment: @ImSoFancy Yes pretty much.

Comment: @ImSoFancy The Text.csv is longer

Comment: The Numpy technique works very well because it allows the usage of numpy to pick apart arrays, and solve them with operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the do_operation content with what you want to do to the value
This does what you specified in your example :

```
def do_operation(x):
    return 10**( - ( float(x) - 2 ) )
input_file_name = str(input("Input file for absorbance/transmittance to be inserted? "))
output_file_name = str(input("What file name is it? "))
with open(output_file_name, 'w') as output_file:
    with open(input_file_name) as input_file :
        for line in input_file :
            vals = line.split(',')
            vals[1] = do_operation(vals[1])
            output_file.write(','.join(vals)+'\n')
```

Edit : 
since you added an actual file ,and it contains floats you might want do a

```
x = float(x)
```

at the first line in do_operation

Comment: output_file.write(','.join(vals)+'\n')
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found               I got this error?

Comment: Is it because I did my def as this                                                                            def do_operation(x):
    x = float(x)
    y = 10**(-(x-2))
    return y

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: do a return str(y)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in-place:

```
import csv
import fileinput
import sys

#file_name = input("Input file for absorbance/transmittance to be inserted? ")
file_name = 'atc.csv'  # Hardcoded for testing.

with fileinput.FileInput(files=file_name, inplace=True, backup='.sav') as csvfile:
    for X, A in csv.reader(csvfile):
        T = 10 ** -(float(A)-2)
        print('{},{}'.format(X, T))

print('done', file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently generated this file snippet which answers my question in a unique way:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt,concatenate,array,savetxt
mdarray= genfromtxt('C:\\DIR\\TEST1.csv',delimiter= ',', skip_header = 1)
percenttransmittance = array([10**(-(A-2)) for A in mdarray[:,1]]).reshape(len(mdarray[:,1]),1)
percenttransmittancearray= concatenate([mdarray[:,0].reshape(len(mdarray[:,1]),1),percenttransmittance], axis =1)
savetxt('C:\\DIR\\PercentTranmittance.csv',percenttransmittancearray,delimiter= ',')
```